# string input copied text

Tags: c++, string

I have for example the following piece of code:

```
string str;
int i;
cout<<"input:";
cin>>str;
cout<<"integer:";
cin>>i;
```

There is actually nothing wrong with this code, but if I paste some text into the command prompt in "input", it automatically fills some of the copied text into "integer". How can I solve this?

Edit: I can type texts as long as I want, but when I copy texts it goes wrong. I don't know why.

Comment: Does your copied text contain line returns ?

Comment: Could you give a sample of what you "paste" at the prompt? Please edit your question with a session of correct and incorrect input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, your text contains white spaces. So, `std::cin` will not work here. Use `std::getline` instead.

```
std::string str;
std::getline( std::cin, str );
```

There's a third parameter of `std::getline` - delimiter. By default, it's the new line char.

---

If your text does contain new line chars, than this will not work. You have 2 options:

- find unique char, that may be used as delimiter and pass it as third parameter of `std::getline`
- read line by line (using `std::getline`) from the user input (`std::cin`) and look for some special string, that will tell your program where the text ends. There's no other way to know where does the `int`eger start (unless the text is with fixed size, but I doubt that)

Comment: @Badshah - Then you have new lines inside your text. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;
int i;
cout<<"input:";
getline(cin, str); 
// you want to read the whole line, operator>> will read until whitespace
cout<<"integer:";
cin>>i;
```